# Как считать первую строку txt на сервере FTP

Tags: python, файлы, ftp

Есть FTP, на нём есть txt, я хочу как-либо прочитать что в первой строке этого файла в python

Comment: Устанавливаете фтп соединение, открываете файл, считываете 1 строку, используете питон. [Смотрите тут](https://python-scripts.com/ftplib)

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ:

```
import urllib.request

u = urllib.request.urlopen("ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/pmc/readme.txt")

for line in u:
    print(line)
```

Первая строка:

```
first = u.readline()
print(first)
```